# How to get an Eigen vector from an Eigen matrix column/row?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, eigen, eigenvector

The thing I want to do is this:

```
MatrixXd M;
// Whatever assigned to `X`
VectorXd V = M(1);
```

Eigen does not support this. Is there a way to retrieve an Eigen vector from an Eigen matrix?

Comment: Curious why this got down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigen [Slicing and Indexing](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSlicingIndexing.html) is of much use here.

To retrieve an `i`-th row vector:

```
VectorXd V = M(i, all);
```

To retrieve an `i`-th column vector:

```
VectorXd V = M(all, i);
```

Comment: `M.row(i)` or `M.col(i)` would work as well (also, prior to Eigen 3.4).